# Jenkinsfile sh echo giving empty result

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to print all the hashfile name and its content using the code given below into a file:

```
    File folder = new File("/Users/workspace/test")
    echo "***Current asset folder is ${folder}***"
    dir ("${folder}"){
      def manifestfile = "${folder}/manifest.txt"
      echo "*** manifestfile location will be ${manifestfile}***"
      echo "**** fetching the files in the folder ******"
      def  FILES_LIST = sh (script: "ls  ${folder}/*.hash", returnStdout: true).trim()
      echo ">>>>>>>>>>>> for loop to fetch the filename and the content <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"
        for (txt in FILES_LIST.split("\\r?\\n")) {
        def finalfile = "${txt}".split('/')[6]
        def content = readFile "${txt}"
        echo "${finalfile}:${content}"
        sh 'echo "$finalfile:$content "'
        }
      }
}
```

The output that i get is given as follows

```
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
testfile.hash:��-�+v�%Aj��o(�
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo :
:
```

You can see sh output is empty, can you help me to fix this as the normal echo and sh echo giving different output, let me know if am doing something wrong.

Thanks
Sreejith

Comment: Please read about Groovy string interpolation, e.g. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. 
I have updated the script to have updated the sh command like given below:
sh "echo $finalfile:$content "
The output that now i get is given below:
/Users/casinodev/.jenkins/workspace/Android@tmp/durable-258856a5/script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: If you want to print _bash_ variable named `finalfile`, you should `echo $finalfile`, or — wrapped in `sh` — `sh "echo \$finalfile" `. But you don't seem to have such a _bash_ var. If you want to print _groovy_ variable named `finalfile`, you should `echo ${finalfile}`, or  — wrapped in `sh` — `sh "echo ${finalfile}" `.

Comment: Thank you for the response @MaratC.
I have found that the hash content were not able to parse to the file due to some special characters. So i changed the way it appends to a file, in groovy i created an empty file and start adding each entry followed by reading the file again to write the file along with the  new entry. Hence i made it work. It was just a work around to reach result.